# VueJS / Vuetify error in rendering a vTable component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have this very simple HTML/Vue/Vuetify code below, that I cannot seem to get working as intended.

```js
const { createApp, computed, ref, reactive } = Vue;
        const { createVuetify } = Vuetify;
        const vuetify = createVuetify();
        const app = createApp({
            setup() {
                const desserts = ref([{
                    name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
                    calories: 159,
                }, {
                    name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
                    calories: 237,
                }, {
                    name: 'Eclair',
                    calories: 262,
                }, {
                    name: 'Cupcake',
                    calories: 305,
                }, {
                    name: 'Gingerbread',
                    calories: 356,
                }, {
                    name: 'Jelly bean',
                    calories: 375,
                }, {
                    name: 'Lollipop',
                    calories: 392,
                }, {
                    name: 'Honeycomb',
                    calories: 408,
                }, {
                    name: 'Donut',
                    calories: 452,
                }, {
                    name: 'KitKat',
                    calories: 518,
                },])

                return {
                    desserts
                }
            }
        });
        app.use(vuetify).mount('#app');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/3.3.19/vuetify.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.3.17/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="app">
        <p>table below this point</p>
        <v-table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-left">URL</th>
                    <th class="text-left"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
           <tbody>
                <tr v-for="item in desserts" :key="item.name">
                    <td class="url">{{ item.name }}</td>
                    <td class="title">{{ item.calories }}</td>
                </tr> 
            </tbody> 
        </v-table>
        <p>table over this point</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to display some data in a simpe vTable `<v-table></v-table>` component (not the `<v-data-table>` coming from the labs).
It however results in a not rendered table, with some errors in the console:

- [Vue warn]: Property "item" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.  at VTable at App
- [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function at VTable at App
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

I checked, the {{deserts}} property is passed to the app, as i can display the array on the page. When removing the <tr for></tr> loop, the HTML found in the devTool is as folows:

```html
<div id="app" data-v-app="">
    <p>table below this point</p>
    <div class="v-table v-theme--light v-table--density-default">
        <!---->
        <div class="v-table__wrapper">
            <table> 
                URL 
            </table>
        </div>
        <!---->
    </div>
    <p>table over this point</p>
</div>
```

I need to work with a solution from Vue and Vuetify grabbed from a CDN as I am just wiring an internal app living in a wordpress page. I might hav got someting wrong, but I can't get my hand on it, as every other components are working ... Been stuck on this for days now, I ruled out any conflict with any other script loaded from WP by putting up this simple JSFiddle.

**EDIT:** just to rule things out, replacing the `<v-table>` by a simple HTML `<table>` works perfectly fine ... Who can explain ?

Comment: ```<v-table>``` - is for vuetify and  ```<table>``` is for HTML. If you are making a web page in vuetify, go with ```v-table```. If you are making a web page in html, go with ```<table>```. Even there is a package, some vuetify style. tag. attributes may not work as normal HTML especially in vuetify 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your template is embedded into the regular page, Vue does not have access to the HTML. Instead, the browser will try to display the page as it normally would, and Vue then uses the DOM nodes as a template.

Browser behavior is vendor-specific, but I think in this case they all work more or less the same:

- The browser does not know the `<v-table>` element, so it just leaves it as it is, assuming something else will deal with it.
- Then it finds table content elements (`<thead>`, `<tr>`, etc.), which it expects to be nested within `<table>` tags, but there was no `<table>`. So they do not make sense, and the browser removes them (including the `v-for`).
- Finally, Vue replaces the `<v-table>` with `<table>` tags, but there is no content left.

To avoid the issue, remove the template code from the HTML page and instead pass it to the component through the `template` property:

```js
const { createApp, computed, ref, reactive } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify;

const vuetify = createVuetify();
const app = createApp({
  template: `
   <p>table below this point</p>
    <v-table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-left">URL</th>
          <th class="text-left"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in desserts" :key="item.name">
          <td class="url">{{ item.name }}</td>
          <td class="title">{{ item.calories }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </v-table>
    <p>table over this point</p>
  `,
  setup() {
    const desserts = ref([{
      name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
      calories: 159,
    }, {
      name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
      calories: 237,
    }, {
      name: 'Eclair',
      calories: 262,
    }, {
      name: 'KitKat',
      calories: 518,
    }, ])

    return {
      desserts
    }
  }
});
app.use(vuetify).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/3.3.19/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.3.17/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div id="app"></div>
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `<table is="vue:v-table">` instead of using `<v-table>` directly:

```js
const { createApp, computed, ref, reactive } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify;

const vuetify = createVuetify();
const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const desserts = ref([{
      name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
      calories: 159,
    }, {
      name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
      calories: 237,
    }, {
      name: 'Eclair',
      calories: 262,
    }, {
      name: 'KitKat',
      calories: 518,
    }, ])

    return {
      desserts
    }
  }
});
app.use(vuetify).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/3.3.19/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.3.17/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div id="app">
  <p>table below this point</p>
    <table is="vue:v-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-left">URL</th>
          <th class="text-left"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in desserts" :key="item.name">
          <td class="url">{{ item.name }}</td>
          <td class="title">{{ item.calories }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>table over this point</p>
</div>
```

This is described in the [in-DOM Template Parsing Caveats section of the docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#element-placement-restrictions)

Comment: Thanks for the insight on the behavior, but then how come t <v-window> element is handled fine (I'm using tabs on the actual fulle script)? Usigng the template property turns to be a hassle to me, as my actual script will be several hundreds of lines of code ... Is there no other solution ?

Comment: Oh, `v-table` is handled fine, too. The table content elements inside the none-table element are the problem. There is an alternative where you use a regular table tag and let Vue override it with a v-table. Have a look at the updated answer